# How to send image and text together to other app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two apps: `App1` which takes an image and assigns it to an address(where the pic was taken), and another app, `App2` which takes image and text(address) from `App1`. When a user clicks on a button in `App1`, I must pass this image and the text to `App2`.

Until now, I am able to successfully send an image to `App2` using `ACTION_SEND`. How shall I also send a text together with image?

I already had a look at this android tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-multiple-content

But it talks about sending multiple images, and not sending image and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making a Parcelable object to hold text and image and send that.
For Parcelable take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.text = "some text";
obj.image = imageUri;

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putExtras("MyObj", obj);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));

public class MyObject implements Parcelable{
private String image;
private String text;
public void setImage(String _image){
image = _image;
}
public void setText(String _text){
text = _text;
}
public String getImage(){
return image;
}
public String getText(){
return text;
}
public MyObject(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }
@Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(image);
        dest.writeString(text);
    }
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

        image = in.readString();
        text = in.readString();
    }
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new MyObject(in);
            }

            public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
                return new MyObject[size];
            }
        };

}
```

Comment: Ok, i get your solution. `MyObject` must implement `Parcelable` interface. But I have one query, what shall I write in the `writeToParcel` method? Can you please add this to your answer? I find the solution interesting since this way I can associate image and text together.

Comment: this object is now parcelable and can be sent through an intent. No need to send text and image separately.

Comment: Hello I try your answer but I get error in this line

Comment: shareIntent.putExtras("MyObj", obj);

Comment: Error:(161, 24) error: no suitable method found for putExtras(String,RecognizeConceptsActivity.MyObject)
method Intent.putExtras(Intent) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Intent.putExtras(Bundle) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Is your object parcelable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sample that you have posted by adding a putExtra for your text:

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
imageUris.add(imageUri1); // Add your image URIs here
imageUris.add(imageUri2);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

now you can add this:

```
shareIntent.putExtra("yourkey", "yourtext");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
```